# Reset Eclipse Screen to Default When First Installed

Tags: eclipse

How do you reset the winds as they were when you originally opened Eclipse.  I accidently closed windows, now I can't find the window that lists the projects, so I can't run anything.
Please advise.  Thanks.

PS Reset Perspectives through the WINDOW tab doesn't work to reset to the default setting, only the last screen, which I screwed up.

Answer (score 71):

You can select "**Window->Perspective->Reset Perspective...**" and click yes.

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that Window, Perspectives does not reset to factory default.

Comment: And what about toolbar? Can I reset toolbar icons order too?

Comment: Very nice .. Good Answer

Comment: "Reset Perspective" does not reset the toolbar, see [Eclipse bug 383569](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383569).
The workaround described in [the third comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383569#c3) (deleting the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench` folder) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 23):

To reset the all Perspectives.

Click on windows - > Perspective - >  Reset Perspective

Comment: "Reset Perspective" does not reset the toolbar, see [Eclipse bug 383569](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383569).
The workaround described in [the third comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383569#c3) (deleting the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench` folder) did the trick for me.

Comment: Goto eclipse bug site and escalating ur issues which u faced

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out.

> Window>Close All Perspectives>Open New Perspective>Java project. – *user966218, Oct 7*

For me this worked except Java project wasn't an option.  Java EE (default) was what I selected under 'Open New Perspective'.  Thanks

Comment: +1, solution works. But, answer should not be mentioning Java as the question did not mention it. It can be mentioned as Window>Close All Perspectives>Open New Perspective>select the required default perspective (Java/Ruby/PHP etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall for factory settings or use 'Window->Show view' to show the windows you'd like

Comment: Unfortunately, the columns that list the projects are not one of the options under Show view.  You must need to select "other" then figure out what you need????

Comment: I figured it out :o)  Window>Close All Perspectives>Open New Perspective>Java project.

Answer (score -1):

You probably inadvertently changed your perspective by double clicking on your java file tab (e.g. HelloWorld.java), as that makes it show only that file. You can change it back by simply double clicking on it again.